# How to get profile images from albums when facebook graph api is localized

Tags: swift, facebook-graph-api

When trying to retrieve links for images from the Facebook Graph API in the album "Profile Pictures" an issue arises when that user has localized their account to another language than english. Then the name of that album changes name according to their localization. That means that you do not know what to search for to find the correct album for their profile pictures.

I have tried to see if I could set a setting for localization in the graph API but without luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the locale parameter to your call/request (locale=en_US)